# Xcode 11 not opening after updating to mac os 10.15 Catalina

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina

I was using Xcode 11 (dmg downloaded from developer account extra files section) on mac os 10.14.6

Today i updated my Mac os to 10.15 catalina to use xcode 11 canvas view but the issue is after updating to mac os 10.15 Catalina i am unable to open xcode. When i clicks on xcode icon it jumps for few seconds and then nothing happens.

I have no backup and projects going on and the main thing is that is my office pc where i work. Please help!!

I tried fixing by this but it didn't helped 
[I can't open Xcode project after updating to Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019534/i-cant-open-xcode-project-after-updating-to-catalina?newreg=a3a64bc8602047efba330fbe3e07d300#)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59621962/2797944

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 11.1 is available on the Mac App Store now so you should probably be using that. Try a force brute approach by deleting Xcode 11, redownload and reinstall.

Comment: For newer Xcode users, an uninstall-reinstall process can get fairly hairy. I'd suggest watching a guide if you've never done it before! If you could install an update in the App Store instead; that might be worth a shot before you do this!

Comment: Just force quitting xcode fixed this issue for me, I had same issue as @BenSmith

Answer (score 5):

I was able to work around this by uninstalling Xcode first. What I did:

- Open Finder and navigate to Applications.
- Move Xcode from Applications to Trash.
- In the terminal, run the command `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer`
- In the terminal, run the command `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`
- Restart your machine.
- Now go to `App Store` and search for `Xcode` and install it from there.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution works exactly for me, see another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76486809/prompt-cant-exec-xcodebuild-operation-not-permitted-after-upgraded-xcode-to-1

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

Close you project then Go to your project file  >  right click on project_name.xcworkspace  >  Show Package Contents >  delete folder xcsharedata  and xcworkspace.

It will create deleted file again once you open that project

Comment: This should be the accepted answer . Nice @Yogesh Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One could also try to perhaps add the program to the list of apps allowed to access the disk.

This can be found under: Settings > Security & Privacy > Privacy > ....

[image: Security And Privacy Settings]

Not directly related: but I just did this for the MS Office Programs (Word, Excel, Powerpoint Outlook etc..).

While in contact with MS Support they advised me to delete everything and reinstall. Adding the programs was a lot easier and retained all my data.