# Prompt "can't exec xcodebuild Operation Not Permitted" after Upgraded Xcode to 12.4 with macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: xcode, macos-catalina, xcodebuild

I am upgrading one of my dev machines to macOS 10.15 (last intel platform) to increase compatibility.

From following webpage: https://xcodereleases.com/, I noticed last compatible version with macOS Catalina 10.15.7 was Xcode 12.4. So I downloaded and replaced the original one from /Applications folder.
[image]

But I encountered some issues after upgrading Xcode, I have tried to launch Xcode via spotlight, but there is no response.
So I tried to launch via terminal command line and get following error.

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
xcodebuild: error: can't exec '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild' (errno=Operation not permitted)
```

I used `xcode-select` to print Xcode path and version, seemed everything looks fine.
Has anyone encountered similar issues before and help me with this?
Thanks.

```
xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

```
xcode-select -v
xcode-select version 2373.
```

Comment: Try completely uninstalling Xcode and all ancillary folders (and don't forget to restart the computer, primitive but it can be important to do). You will lose your prefs etc but what do you have to lose? Then do a clean install of the new Xcode. — Also make sure if you have the command line tools that they are in sync with your new version of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks @matt Could you be more specific about completely uninstalling Xcode? I am now deleting legacy Xcode from /Applications folder and drag new version in rather than dragging in directly. I have also installed the corresponding command line tools and restarted the machine. But all these seemed does not help, I made some online search before posting this thread, hoping can get some advice/suggestions/clues from this professional community :)

Comment: I was thinking of this sort of thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58307386/xcode-11-not-opening-after-updating-to-mac-os-10-15-catalina A lot of people hit a wall with Catalina so I thought their experience might be useful.

Comment: Also what happens with Xcode 12.1? It was the last Intel only version. Can you run that one?

Comment: Thank you so much @matt The link you shared works exactly for me 

Comment: Regarding the question with Xcode 12.1, please see my posted link: https://xcodereleases.com/, you can see last version compatible with macOS 10.15.7 is Xcode 12.4. This can be read from my original post as well, I've highlighted that one from snapshot.

Comment: That's great! I'll close this as a duplicate, but let's not delete it because it might work as another way into the issue.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking that 12.4 might introduce complications because it is also compatible with Apple Silicon, whereas 12.1 is Intel only. That's why I suggesting trying to launch 12.1 as an experiment. But if the problem is solved, there's no need for that experiment!

Comment: Yes @matt, as I've put more details in this thread, also errno from this post is different from another thread you shared with me, but the solution worked for both!!

Comment: Yes @matt, last version purely for intel platform would be **Xcode 12.1.1**, which can be referred from link: https://xcodereleases.com/