# iCloud folders only partially visible to applications in MacOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

It appears that only locally loaded files are visible for iCloud folders in 10.15 Catalina. This had not been a problem in 10.14 and appears to be breaking numerous applications.

Notice which files here (Sorted largest first) are not local (Little cloud symbol)

[image: Largest files listed in the 10.15 Finder]

and which files are visble to **/bin/ls**

[image: A bash shell running **/bin/ls** in size order]

Notice that the first local file in the **Finder** is dratisDifference.js and that the second is an iStock photo containing 82.100. These are the first two files discoverable by **ls**. It's not that they are in a different location in the sort order. They are not visible to **ls** at all. They appear not to exist.

This appears to be the cause of many problems for applications (github, IDEs etc.) running under 10.15 where files are just found to be missing from the file system.

Comment: For example: $ /bin/ls Landing_Optimized.png results in "
ls: Landing_Optimized.png: No such file or directory"

Comment: They are visible as ls -a .*.icloud though no applicaiton will be searching for them under that name.