# Xcode version 12.0.1 not opening .workspace files

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]Okay, I updated my mac os to Catalina today, as well as updating the xcode version to 12.0.1. I am now unable to get the .workspace file to open in xcode. Every time I try to open the workspace file the xcode it brings up the .xcodeproj file in the tab above the project directory. I've also tried to get the file open from inside xcode, and that also doesn't work.

I have a legacy build and have updated the pods and packages.

Any help with this would be super helpful because I'm not sure what to do at this point.

I've tried restarting my computer and xcode, and removing my xcworkspace file and the pods and pods.lock files. and then running pod install again. and nothing has helped get the workspace file to open in the xcode app.

Comment: Can you show a screen shot?

Comment: edited! sorry about that!

Comment: I looked at your screen shot and what I see is exactly what I expect to see for a project with pods — the project file and the pods file, and their dependencies. What's the issue here? The workspace file _is open_. Go for it.

Comment: in the past when I've used the xcworkspace files it hasn't said it was an xcodeproject file. and I keep getting"Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_NativeStorage in NativeStorage.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NativeStorage in NativeStorage.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NativeStorage.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" errors 1/2

Comment: 2/2 and i was under the impression that those errors were from using .xcodeproject file, and not the .xcworkspace file

Comment: I know nothing of that. The question was "I am now unable to get the .workspace file to open in xcode". I'm telling you it _is_ open.

Comment: okay, thanks, i appreciate the confirmation

Comment: did you ever solve this issue? I notice the answer from @matt but it makes no sense to me in my case (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630927/clicking-xcworkspace-opens-xcodeproj)

Comment: did i solve the issue with the _OBJC_CLASS, or if the file was a workspace file?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue after updated OS to Catalina v10.15.7 and Xcode v12.0.1. I deleted `.xcworkspace` and created new `.xcworkspace` by `pod install` using terminal.

Answer (score 0):

So I have discovered that the project file (project.pbxproj)is not being edited properly by Xcode when adding a new group to the project. Here is how our team resolved the issue (image below):

[image]

1. Go to and open project.pbxproj (cd [YOUR PROJECT] -> cd [YOUR PROJECT].xcodeproj -> open project.pbxproj

[image]

2. Find the missing group annotation

[image]

3. Add missing annotations

[image]

And walah...Xcode is humming again! :)

[image]