# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code, Xcode 12.4

Tags: xcode12, xcode-workspace, xcodeproj

I am able to run my app on simulator. On real device however, I am asked to give my keychain password, whereafter the build fails with

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

From the log:

```
path/to/AppAuth.framework: errSecInternalComponent
```

I have tried to delete derived data, clean my project, restart both xcode and my machine, delete the workspace and podfile.lock and generate new ones. Nothing helps.

Any ideas? Is this a code signing/certificate issue?

I noticed that in my Xcode project navigator, under Pods/Frameworks, all frameworks are red, including AppAuth.framework. Looking at the frameworks full path in the Xcode file inspector, I notice that the path referred to does not exist. The path points to a 'Debug' folder under DerivedData/Products, but I only have a 'Debug-iphoneos', under which I can see the framework. I assume this explains the framework being red (ie cannot be found)?

Would "correcting" the full path perhaps solve all this, and how would I do that?

Comment: got the same error,any solutions now? Xcode 12.5

Comment: @Ben see my answer.

Comment: i solve this by restart mac,reopen Xcode. gosh~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had some certificate duplicates. Once I got them sorted out the app compiles. Frameworks still red though.